# Jmeter-5.0 : Are RPS (Request per second) and TPS (Transaction per sec) same?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

What is the difference between RPS and TPS in Jmeter? I want to run Jmeter script for 5 minutes ramp up time for each target TPS: 10, 20 and 30. 
Is it same of RPS?

Answer (score 3):

The difference between requests per second and transactions per second is that a transaction might consist of several requests.
In JMeter a transaction is - pretty obviously - represented by a [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller).

To illustrate that:

- open your Chrome (or browser of choice)
- open the devtools (F12 in chrome)
- select the network tab
- browse to https://www.google.com

Whereas your transaction is "Open Google Landing Page" your browser performs over a dozen single requests.

If you want to generate a certain amount of requests (or transactions?) have a look at [JMeter Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers). The [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) might be a good start! Please be aware, that the scope of the timer matters!

Answer (score 2):

[TPS](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/)

> counts for each seconds the number of finished transactions

Is equal to [RPS](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-adjust-the-rps-in-your-jmeter-test-via-the-command-line/) in JMeter

> “translate” RPS to “sample per minute”.

Actually you can call it *SPS*, because JMeter context is counting **sample** and not request/transaction

Comment: So, basically both are same? Any idea how can I achieve my target ?

Comment: @testingUser yes, there are no real transactions in JMeter, only samplers. see TPS link for plugin to reach TPS

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look.